# Javascript pop up message in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp, servlets

Without creating a new page jsp file, is there a way I can make a popup "Data inserted successfully" message appear after I have inserted registration data into a table successfully.
Pop up in the sense that no new browser window is created but the message appears in a new box within the current web page and when clicked "Ok", redirects me to the next web page in the TRY SECTION.

```
<%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Statement"%>
<%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%!
     String firstname, lastname, address, phoneNo;
     String sex, password;
     %>
     <%
     firstname = lastname = address = phoneNo= "";
     sex = ""; password = "";
     firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
     lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
     address= request.getParameter("address").trim();
     phoneNo = request.getParameter("phoneNo");
     sex = request.getParameter("Sex");
     password = request.getParameter("password");
     if(firstname.equals("")|| lastname.equals("")|| phoneNo.equals("")||
             sex.equals("")|| password.equals(""))
     {
         out.write("Empty fields, make sure you input data into all field before pushing the  " +
                    "REGISTER button");
     }
     else
     {
         String sql1="INSERT INTO customer_details  VALUES('"+firstname+"', '"+lastname+"','"+address+"', '" +phoneNo+"',' "+sex+ "','"+password+"')"; 
         String sql2 = "INSERT INTO verification VALUES('"+firstname+"', '"+password+"')";
         try{
             Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + "onlineburgerapp","root", "root");
             Statement st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
             st.executeUpdate(sql1);
             st.executeUpdate(sql2);

             conn.setAutoCommit(true);
             conn.close();
             response.sendRedirect("availableBurgers.jsp");
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();}
         }
     %>
</body>
```

Comment: Javascript 's `confirm` can be used.

Comment: Use of Java code inside scriptlets is not encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert JavaScript code into JSP code.
For example:

```
<%
try{

%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Inserted Successfully");
</script>
<%
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand properly your problem: if your SQL requests are successful, you want to display a 'success' message/popup to the user.

How do you request this JSP you show here?
If it is a classic webbrowser request (let's assume), since at the end, it redirects to the `availableBurgers.jsp`, this page won't send any content to your browser.

I would just set the success popup in the `availableBurgers.jsp` since this is your success page.

Answer (score 0):

An improvement to the selected good answer:
if you want to customize your message with some variables you have:

```
<%
try {
    String myVariable = "Successfully";
%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myMessage;
<%
    out.println("myMessage = \"I have inserted "+myVariable+"\"");
%>
    alert(myMessage);
    </script>
<%
    } catch(Exception e) {
}
%>
```